# Layer materials within a single face?

Tags: materials, transparency

Is there a way in Blender to layer one material on top of another via alpha channels? Here's the use case: I have a material that I've applied to a bunch of different objects. On one of them, I'd like to apply an image, basically as a sticker.

I recognize this is doable if I duplicate the base material's node setup, combine it with the sticker, and apply that new material to the faces in question. But now I've got two copies of my base material node setup, which isn't ideal.

What I'd *like* to be able to do is keep the base material on everything, then add a second sticker material that I apply to the faces I want. Anywhere on those faces where the sticker material's alpha is zero, I'd just see the base.

I have not been able to find a way to do this; there are similar questions here, but they all get answered with a node-based solution as described above. I've also played with the blend modes in the material tab, but none seems to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would add the image of the stickers to the original material and UV the objects in such a way that all the faces that don't have stickers on them will be projected on a part of the image that is completely transparent. But obviously, if your base material uses a texture it will mess with that UV map too. If that's the case, sadly you're stuck with creating seperate materials.

Comment: Huh. Surprising there's no way to do this. (I came from Cinema 4D before this, and it's an easy thing to do there.)

Comment: Blender still is a community software that is free to use. It's unfair to compare it to C4D. Though Blender is a very well iterated piece of software considering it's free.

Comment: I think the comparison, fair or no, is inevitable since anyone looking to do this kind of work will end up having to pick. And, as you say, Blender is really mature at this point—someone who can afford something like C4D might consider Blender purely on its feature set.